# Inheriting object and passing variables to it, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object

I think code will explain better than words. Basically the goal is that only **Customizable** section should be edited in future (means, 400, 500 etc should be added without interfering with code in **Static** section).

Right now I'm trying to pass **screenId**. You could say that I Can just replace function() with function(id) but that's not the only variable I will be passing in future therefore it would be great if I could `inherit` those variables like I could inherit `this.id` between prototypes **without** need to pass them as function's argument.

Code you can find here: http://jsfiddle.net/J4pK6/

Thanks in advance for your time and support.

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be fixed by using `screens[screenId].content.call(this);`
Reworked code

Reference:[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)
Thanks to [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling)